# Boundary Fences UK: What Comes Under Class A, Part 2 Schedule 2 of the General Permitted Development Order 2015 (Amended)?

Tags: england-and-wales, real-estate, safety, local-authorities, zoning

Edited Question for Improvement

What residences/businesses come under Class A, [Part 2 Schedule 2 of the General Permitted Development Order 2015 (Amended)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2015/596/schedule/2/part/2/crossheading/class-a-gates-fences-walls-etc?timeline=false)?

I am looking into the defintion of Free Standing with relation to Class A, Part 2 Schedule 2 of the General Permitted Development Order 2015 (Amended).

Is the SCREEN in the following a Free Standing Structures in UK Planning?

In all cases the screen is 336cm tall and about 1m wide. It is a wooden frame covered with tarpaulin. Some of the frame goes into the ground. It acts like a sail in the wind. In all cases the fence is a border fence between two properties subject to a 2m height.

1. If the wooden frame of the screen is screwed to the fence? Is it free standing?
2. If the screws are removed and the screen is propped up with 2 shovels. It would fall over in the wind if the shovels were not there. Is it free standing then?
3. If the screws and shovels are removed, but a large stone at the base then wedges the screen to the fence. It would fall over in the wind if the stone was removed. Is it free standing then?
4. In all cases the screen would fall over in the wind if the fence did not exist at all. Is it free standing then?
5. In all these cases (with the fence there or with no fence), would the screen be considered part of the boundary enclosure?

Comment: Ah, the common language that divides us! In American English a "border fence" is a fence along the boundary of a government jurisdiction like between United States and Mexico or around East Berlin, and we call what is referred to in this question a "boundary fence". I saw the headline and imagined an underwater fence in the English channel. Just an aside.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the title.

Comment: Whether or not it is free standing does not seem to be relevant for this Part, what matters is whether it is an "*other means of enclosure*" which isn't evident from the question. Can  you clarify, please.

Comment: What is an 'other means of enclosure'? Can you direct me to a link of these rules, because I cannot find one?

Comment: @Rick I have added more detail in the question.

Comment: It's the title of the Part you referenced  "*The erection, construction, maintenance, improvement or alteration of a gate, fence, wall or **other means of enclosure.***" and is mentioned five times in A1.

Comment: Someone else edited the question, and put that link it. I will look at it now.

Comment: @Rick OK, I see the phrase, but cannot find the definition.

Comment: I added the link to save others from Googling it.  And the definition isn't in the Order as it will be fact-specific according to the particular set of circumstances.  i.e. what purpose does the tarp serve? Is it an enclosure akin to a fence or is it e.g. an artistic display, windbreak, sun shade etc..?